# Does anyone know if US patent 20100316986 A1, "Rubric-based assessment with personalized learning recommendations", has actually been granted?

Tags: us20100316986

Does anyone know if US patent 20100316986 A1, "Rubric-based assessment with personalized learning recommendations", has actually been granted?  The Google link seems to indicate that it is an "application".  This particular patent, applied for by Microsoft will be burdensome for the entire eLearning industry should they every try to enforce it.

Answer (score 1):

I looked it up in USPTO Public PAIR (see the FAQs to learn how to do this). The current status is "final rejection mailed".

[image]

This is the second "final" rejection. They have narrowed the claims from those that show in the published application you cited. Microsoft can appeal or otherwise keep narrowing, arguing and fighting to get some version through.